# It's an intriguing word, but should it be an SO tag?: Heisenbug

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I just noticed the tag **[Heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heisenbug)**. There are only 15 questions tagged with it.

I assume this is a bug that's hard to track down.

Just thought I'd open a discussion as to whether it's a proper tag, since I'm not sure whether `De-Heisenbugging` is really substantially different from **[debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging)** (~4000 questions).

Comment: Just to be clear - I'm voting up 'cos it _should_ be a tag.

Comment: There may be more than 15, but looking at them changes them. But more seriously, it is a common, understood term so I reckon let it be.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say yes, it can be a distinct tag - bugs and debugging are bread and butter.  But bugs that go away only when you diagnose them - which is what the term 'Heisenbug' means to me - are different ... and annoying!

(*[See also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug)*)